# How to reuse connections or use connection pooling in GraphQL of Apollo-server REST datasource

Tags: node.js, apollo, connection-pooling, apollo-server

I have a GraphQL server with `apollo-server` and `apollo-datasource-rest` as library to handle REST datasource connections.

I am facing an issue of opening too many connections from GraphQL to my cloud hosted services due to a high number of concurrent requests.

When the GraphQL server fires a request to a REST service there is a middle step in the cloud infrastructure to get service's private ip by using [Azure SNAT for outbound connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections)

However, due to the high number of connections on every new request the SNAT ports get exhausted.

One of the possible ways to avoid this problem is to use connection pooling or reuse existing connections for new requests according [to this article](https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/).

[image: Possible ways to solve port exhaustion]

My question is how to reuse existing connections in Apollo-server or how to implement connection pooling so I solve this issue.